# Django Rest Framework TypeError with browsable API only

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Consider the following viewset:

```
class FooBarView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = FooBarSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = self.get_queryset()
    serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def get_queryset(self):
    user = self.request.user
    return FooBar.objects.filter(user=user)
```

the following model:

```
class FooBar(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    other fields ...
```

and the follwing serializer

```
class FooBarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FooBar
        fields = ('user', other fields ...)
```

This viewset works perfectly with the JsonRenderer, but the BrowsableAPIRenderer raises a TypeError on both the retrieve and list routes:

`__str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)`

`/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py in display_value, line 228`

```
def display_value(self, instance):
    return six.text_type(instance)
```

Local Vars

```
instance: Error in formatting: TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)

self: PrimaryKeyRelatedField(allow_null=True, queryset=User.objects.all(), required=False, validators=[<UniqueValidator(queryset=FooBar.objects.all())>])
```

If i remove the user field from the serializer it works fine.
The `FooBar` instance has a user, all of the others fields are as intented as well.

Any idea where this could come from ?

I'm running python3.6 with django2.0 and DRF3.9.0

Comment: Have you tried defining `__str__` in `FooBar`?  The error is saying the method for `__str__`  is returning `None`.  This can happen if you haven't defined `__str__`.  Because `user` is a class object and not a simple type, `FooBar` doesn't know how to turn `user` into a string object.

Comment: Yes `__str__` is defined on both `FooBar` and `User`.

Comment: What does your `__str__` look like for `User` model? You have an empty field somewhere in a related model and are returning it. Probably doing something like `return self.username` rather than `return self.username or ''`